# How would one create a DATE column that is updated via a DATETIME column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Consider the following:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable 
(
    [id] INT NOT NULL,
    [foobar] VARCHAR(25) NULL,
    [created_on] DATETIME NOT NULL
);

SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE CAST(created_on AS DATE) = '2019-01-01';
```

I have a lot of queries like this, where I need to store the full date and time for audit (and sorting) purposes, but most queries only care about the date portion when it comes to searching.

In order to improve performance, I was considering adding a sister column that stores the value as a `DATE`, and then update it via triggers; but before I go down that rabbit hole, I wanted to know if there is a better way to solve this issue. Is there some mechanism in SQL Server that offers a better solution to this issue?

I am currently stuck on SQL Server 2008, but I am open to solutions that use newer versions

Comment: Do not believe adding an extra column and duplicating data is best, but if this is createdate, it should never change correct?  Then you could just have a default on the column to populate with GetDate().

Comment: Depends on what would make another solution "better" for your purposes.

Comment: "better" for my purposes would be better performance than having to cast the date to DATE whenever I just need the date portion.

Answer (score 4):

My preference would be to just write a sargable

```
WHERE created_on >= '2019-01-01' and created_on < '2019-01-02';
```

The

```
CAST(created_on AS DATE) = '2019-01-01';
```

Is in fact [mostly sargable but somewhat sub optimal](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34052/3690) ...

... and splitting it out into a separate indexed column can help other cases like `GROUP BY date`

If you decide you do need a separate column you can create a computed column and index that.

This is preferable to triggers as it has less performance overhead as well as allowing SQL Server to match both the column name and the original expression. (any index on a column populated by a trigger won't be matched to a query containing `CAST(created_on AS DATE)`)

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
  (
     [id]         INT NOT NULL,
     [foobar]     VARCHAR(25) NULL,
     [created_on] DATETIME NOT NULL,
     [created_on_date] AS CAST(created_on AS DATE)
  );

CREATE INDEX ix_created_on_date
  ON mytable(created_on_date)
  include (foobar, id, created_on)

SELECT foobar,
       id,
       created_on
FROM   mytable
WHERE  CAST(created_on AS DATE) = '2019-01-01';
```

[image]

Comment: And you could also make that `created_on_date` **PERSISTED** to avoid recalculating it on every read access. That might improve performance, too

Comment: If the column is pulled from the index it is persisted there anyway. The PERSISTED only affects what happens in the table data pages. And it is cheap to compute anyway so may not be worth the overhead